# REST API and iPhone App Architecture and Code Structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, api-design

Background:
I am in the early stages of an an iPhone App and REST WebService product.  Basically, I have a database on the a server and have written some REST APIs to access this database.  I have a companion iPhone app that will consume these REST APIs.

Questions:
What is the best approach to place the code for accessing the REST APIs?  Should I create a separate subclass of `NSObject` and place the interface and implementation details there?  I would like to reduce the amount of code duplication throughout the application in the various ViewControllers that would interact with the REST API.

For Example:
My app would start up and make a REST API call to determine the current state of local information on the device by comparing the value returned from the API vs local.  Then I would initiate an update request from the API to refresh the local datastore.

Now if I have all of this logic in the start-up ViewController I have multiple calls using `NSURLConnection` which only has on delegate.  I don't know how to make these separate calls in the same ViewController.

What are some approaches to solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I generally create custom objects which use ASIHTTPRequest (using composition, not subclassing) which can be initialised with any required parameters, and use that to manage requests to the RESTful service. The custom object will provide a delegate protocol for handling success, failure and other custom notifications so that I can use this feedback to update the application UI while the request is performed asynchronously.

If you need to parse large amount of data returned from a request, make sure you launch a separate thread to do this, rather than doing it in your HTTP request success callback, otherwise this will keep the network activity spinner active longer than it actually should be.

If you need to manage multiple requests of the same type, you could add a "tag" property to your custom request, so that when your success/failure delegate response is called, you can easily identify which request it belongs to without having to keep an instance variable to the original request.